# dotnet add package bootstrap gives 404 error with source nuget.org

Tags: .net-core, nuget, bootstrap-4, asp.net-core-2.1, dotnet-cli

I'm trying to add bootstrap to a new dotnet core razor app.

```
C:\dev\core>dotnet --version
2.1.302
```

I created the project with the command below and have made any changes yet.

```
dotnet new razor
```

But now when I try to add the bootstrap nuget package I get the following error.  Is this supposed to work?  The package is present on the nuget website at https://www.nuget.org/packages/bootstrap/4.1.1

```
C:\dev\core>dotnet add package bootstrap -v 4.1.1 -s http://nuget.org
  Writing C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpA9E3.tmp
info : Adding PackageReference for package 'bootstrap' into project 'C:\dev\core\myproj.csproj'.
log  : Restoring packages for C:\dev\core\myproj.csproj...
info :   GET http://nuget.org/FindPackagesById()?id='bootstrap'&semVerLevel=2.0.0
info :   NotFound http://nuget.org/FindPackagesById()?id='bootstrap'&semVerLevel=2.0.0 2324ms
log  : Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsyncCore' for source 'http://nuget.org/FindPackagesById()?id='boo
tstrap'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'.
log  : Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found).
info :   GET http://nuget.org/FindPackagesById()?id='bootstrap'&semVerLevel=2.0.0
info :   NotFound http://nuget.org/FindPackagesById()?id='bootstrap'&semVerLevel=2.0.0 705ms
log  : Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsyncCore' for source 'http://nuget.org/FindPackagesById()?id='boo
tstrap'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'.
log  : Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found).
info :   GET http://nuget.org/FindPackagesById()?id='bootstrap'&semVerLevel=2.0.0
info :   NotFound http://nuget.org/FindPackagesById()?id='bootstrap'&semVerLevel=2.0.0 698ms
error: Failed to retrieve information about 'bootstrap' from remote source 'http://nuget.org/FindPa
ckagesById()?id='bootstrap'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'.
error:   Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found).
```

Comment: can you browse NuGet from right click project> Manage NuGet packages ?

Comment: @saj No it's not listed in visual studio, but I'm curious as to why the command line doesn't work.

Comment: i would not recommend using nuget client-side libraries for .net core. They aren't meant to be used for .net core and cause several issues in the long run. you can use something like yarn

Answer (score 1):

It seems that to access the nuget.org packages, `api.nuget.org` is the source to use.  This command worked:

```
dotnet add package bootstrap -v 4.1.1 -s http://api.nuget.org
```

Comment: i don't think this was the root cause. that is the default source and it works without the source for me. However, these will still not get you the bootstrap files

Comment: I added the source because the default source wasn't nuget for me after installing dotnet core 2.1.302 under windows.  Maybe I made a change to the sources a while ago.

Comment: but are you able to use bootstrap now? did you find the js and css files?

Comment: no, but I'll try npm or yarn as you suggested, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have a NuGet.config with wrong sources.

You may have correctly configured Nuget sources globally, but the Nuget.config has a non-existent source.